# How to do line break correctly, without comma (angular-material tooltip)?

Tags: angular-material, tooltip, line-breaks, angular12

My code HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="participants">
        <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Уч.</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" matTooltip="{{ row.participants | 
            displayUserTooltip }}">
          {{ row?.participants?.length }}
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

My SCSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {font-size: rem(12px);margin-right: 10px;white-space: pre-line;}
```

My pipe :

```
 transform(items: any[]): any {
if (items) {
  return items?.map(({ employee }) => ` ${employee.surname} ${employee.name} ${employee.patronymic}`+'\n');
}
```

}

Current result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGsmh.png)

tell me how can I transfer a line without a comma?
Where does this comma come from?
I've tried working with the string --- replace (',', '\ n') --- it didn't help.
line break works in pair '\ n' + white-space: pre-line;

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
 if (items) {
  return items?.map(({ employee }) => 
  ` ${employee.surname} ${employee.name} ${employee.patronymic + ' '.replace(' ', '\n')}`).join(' ');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQkTN.png)